# .py files opens up in a text editor when run from cmd

Tags: python

Whenever I try to run a .py file from cmd it opens up in a text editor(np++). I'm trying to run the following:

```
django-admin.py startproject testprj
```

Even if I run 'setup.py install'

Comment: What platform? Does django-admin.py have a #! at the top?

Comment: @Nathon: Notepad++ is for Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the file association so that .py files open with Python executable, typically located in `C:\Python<version>\` and not Notepad++

Changing this should be easy, but [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028161/windows-10-change-default-programs) is how to do it.

Also, read [here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-run-a-python-program-under-windows.htm) on to set the environment path so that the Python executable is found without you having to navigate to C:\Python2.6.

Comment: The link is bad.  Also, relevant information should be posted in the answer so it doesn't happen :)

Comment: Pls add the instructions to your answer, the first link isn't working

Answer (score 1):

Your Windows file associations are set to open `.py` files in a text editor. You have to change those to use the `python.exe` interpreter, or you can prefix all your commands with python, like this:

`python django-admin.py startproject testprj`

If you want to change your file associations, and you are running Vista or Windows 7, you can change them in 'Control Panel'->'Default Programs'->'Associate a file type or protocol with a program'

Comment: I'm running the as u said and even set the path to %path%;C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\bin but it is giving django-admin.py file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the answers.
After changing the default exec to open .py files, you might need to change scripts are opened, so that all the command line arguments are passed to the script.
You can do it using Registry Editor (regedit).

1. Open Start Menu and type: ***regedit***
2. In the editor go to:

   `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\py.exe\shell\open\command`
3. modify the value to be equal to: ***C:\Windows\py.exe "%1" %****